# PHP Game of stones returns boolean instead of winner

Tags: php, return-value, game-loop

The following code is for a game. It creates an array of N consecutive stones, an the players Alice and Bob will alternatively pick two consecutive stones (subtracts the value and leaves a 'gap') each time until there is no consecutive stones. That means the array has no values without a gap in between.

I think the code for the game is complete. But when I call it only shows a boolean(true). Instead of the name of the winner.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class GameOfStones {

    // Define while the index contains a stone (O) or not.

    const STONE = 'O';
    const STONE_PAIR = 'OO';
    const GAP = '';

    // Save the random result in a open/public variable.

    public $line;
    public $winner;

    // Set the winning rules for the game.

    public function win($winner) {
        if (is_finished === true) {     
            if ($nStones % 2 == 1) {
                echo "Alice" . '<br>';
            } 
            else {
                echo "Bob" . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }

    // Create the indexed line of stones

    public function create_line($nStones){
        return array_fill(0, $nStones, 'O');
    }


    // Removes a pair of stones from the line at nth location.

    public function remove($n)
    {
        while($game->is_finished() !== true) {

            if(substr($this->line, $n-1, 2) == self::STONE)
                $this->line =
                    substr_replace($this->line, self::GAP , $n-1, 2);
            else
                throw new Exception('Invalid move.');
        }
    }


// Check if there are no further possible moves.

public function is_finished()
{
    return strpos($this->line, self::STONE_PAIR) === false;
}

};
$game = new GameOfStones(rand(1,10000000));

 var_dump($game->is_finished());
     $game->remove(rand($n));
     var_dump($game->is_finished());
    var_dump($game->win());
echo $nStones;
printf($winner);
?>
```

Comment: boolean(true) is the return value you are getting from your first var_dump in `var_dump($game->is_finished());`. Your code is then failing when calling remove function

Comment: There are a few mistakes in the code, in the `win()` method, you reference `$nStones` which isn't defined in the method or at class level.  The `remove()` method references `$game`. You reference `$n` and `$winner` in the end code without declaring them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling a `constant` `is_finished` instead of your method `is_finished()`. Try replacing

```
public function win($winner) {
    if (is_finished === true) {     
        if ($nStones % 2 == 1) {
            echo "Alice" . '<br>';
        } 
        else {
            echo "Bob" . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

With

```
public function win($winner) {
    if ($this->is_finished() === true) {     
        if ($nStones % 2 == 1) {
            echo "Alice" . '<br>';
        } 
        else {
            echo "Bob" . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

boolean(true) is the return value you are getting from your first var_dump in `var_dump($game->is_finished());`

In `remove()` function, `$game` variable doesn't exist. Instead you should check for `$this` since `remove()` is already a class function

```
 while($this->is_finished() !== true)
```

Also, in `win()` function, you are not calling `is_finished` function correctly.

```
 if ($this->is_finished() === true)
```